# How to write a json file which contains two arraylists<String>

Tags: java, json, string, arraylist

I have to read from JSON file to two arraylist which one contains question and second contains answer but I don't know how to write that file. It's going to be a simple quiz. Can anyone give me an example

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2591098/5810051. Possibile duplicate

Comment: Nothing at all because I have no clue how should it look like. It's just a programm for my classes and my instructor haven't explained anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
{
   "questions":
   [
        "What is the capital of France?",
        "What is the answer to everything?"
   ],
   "answers":
   [
        "Paris", 
        "forty-two"
   ]
}
```

An alternative way would bundling question-answer-pairs:

```
[
   {
     "q": "What is the capital of France?",
     "a": "Paris" 
   },
   {
     "q": "What is the answer to everything?",
     "a": "42" 
   }
]
```

It depends on your application which way is more convenient and natural.

Comment: Got your point so if I would have next question and aswear just need to add after comma?

Comment: No, you would extend the lists. Will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
 "questions":["Question1","Question2","Question3"],
 "answers":["Answer1","Answer2","Answer3"]
}
```

i suggest you to create a simple class for generate the Json from an Object

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class JavaToJson
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {

    ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();
    test.add("Question1");
    test.add("Question2");

    try
    {
        String jsonStr = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(test);
        System.out.println("test: "+jsonStr);
    }
    catch (JsonProcessingException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

so the variable "jsonStr" will be the json you are looking for.